# What happens when partition is paused and re-balance happens?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What happens when Kafka partition is paused by consumer and re-balance is triggered ?
Partition remains paused when assigned to new consumer or it will get resumed ?

I got mixed answers when searched for it. Couldn't get Kafka documentation on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a rebalance happens, all partitions are resumed.

This is because pausing a partition is a decision local to a consumer. The rest of the group is not aware of that.

If you have logic in a consumer that can pause partitions based on some conditions, when partitions are reassigned, your logic can pause them again based on the same conditions. The same happens for other consumers which are presumably running the same logic.

---

Note that answering this type of question is relatively easy. You can just give it a try and see what happens. It's also a great way to improve your understanding of Kafka!

Comment: Thanks Mickael. I gave a try and got to know depending on logic, ConsumerRebalanceListener also might need to implement to pause the partitions.